# Objective-c Print a Const Void Variable

Tags: objective-c, pointers, printf

print the value of a const void* what i need do ?

for example:

```
- (void) printConstVoid:(const void*)value
{
    NSLog("%?",value); //or anything else print the value
}
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: It entirely depends what you have stored there - printable characters, or something else ? Or do you just want the value of the pointer itself (i.e. the address it points to) ?

Comment: Do you want to print the memory address, or what the memory address points to?

Comment: @PaulR it was a nsdata instance, but dont have a generic way?

Comment: @zneak i want print the value of variable :)

Comment: @ademar111190, we got that. But it's ambiguous whether the "value" of the variable, for you, is its actual value  (which is a _pointer_, in other words an integer representing a memory address), or what `value` points to.

Comment: If it's NSData it shouldn't be a `(const void*)`, it should be `NSData*`, and you'd format it with `%@`.

Comment: @HotLicks I call the method printConstVoid:[nsdatInstance bytes]; because I need a const void*.

Comment: *Why* do you need a `const void *` ?

Comment: @PaulR because i go send this to a library method, and the param of this method is a const void*, i used a mock method called printConstVoid to exemplify it in a easy way, i want print to see if i'm sending a correct value to this method.

Comment: Why not just make the library method have the proper signature?

Comment: @PaulR because it isn`t my library :/, and i can`t modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog( @"%p", value );
```

It will print the pointer value (memory address).

Comment: dont have a way to print the value?

Comment: @ademar111190, you should edit your question to include what you would expect exactly. A void pointer means that the language and the libraries are not aware of the kind of data being referenced, so we can't help a lot either.

Comment: @zneak understood, i go add thid detail, thanks a lot :)

Comment: the print of pointer works bit i want see the value if possible

Comment: @ademar111190 - The value of a pointer ***is*** its memory address.  This is different from the value of whatever the pointer points to.

Comment: @HotLicks understood, allright I go print the pointer. would be an interesting way to get the most value but pointer already serves.

Answer (score 5):

The thing is, `const void *` is just a way of saying "this is a pointer to something." It tells you nothing about what the thing actually is, so the only generic way to print it is with the "%p" format specifier mentioned by Macmade, which will show the pointer value.

In order to print the thing being pointed to, you need to know what that thing is. In fact, in order to do *anything* with a `const void *` besides pass it around, you need to cast it to a more specific type. A `const void *` is completely opaque until you cast it.

Comment: understood, so I go print like the Macmade, but thanks to detailed explanation, the truth is not really understood what the const voids * was.